# when apply "chattr +a" on a folder, vim automatically generate numbered file

Tags: vim

I have a folder called Text/, and I applied "**chattr +a**" on that folder as root to prevent deleting files, while allowing creation of new files inside the folder.

I created a new file inside this folder, but every time I changed the content of the file, it automatically generate a numbered file in the same directory, like 5036, 5159

should anyone know what's up? I tried to change the backupdir and dir(for swap file) in vimrc, but still not work.

If you have any idea on this issue, please help me, thanks!

Comment: Are you able to write to the file using other tools? Does the original file disappears after the numbered file is created? What OS are you using?

Comment: yes, I can edit it with either vim or nano on CentOS 6.4, there is no problem with nano, so I guess it would be some sort of cache by vim, well, can't figure out

Comment: when applied "**chattr +a**" on a folder, files can only be added to the folder, but can't be deleted from it (which is my purpose), when I remove the **+a** attribute with "**chattr -a**", the numbered files no longer generated (former ones still remained), thank you for your reply

Comment: maybe vim is creating those files instead of the hidden swp files since it cannot remove the swps.

Comment: well, when I was editing the file, I can see the swap file in my home directory (~/.vim/swap/), and if I change the content of the file then save, a new numbered file was created which is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Vim makes a backup before overwriting a file, which is deleted after the file is successfully written. As you mentioned on the comments, `chattr +a` prevents the removal of those bakcup files.

The generation of backup files can be disabled with `:set nowritebackup` for all files; `backupskip` option can be used to disable the backup only for folders with restrict attributes. Additional information on `:h backup-table`.

Comment: The problem has been settled when I **set nobackup** , **set nowritebackup** and **set dir=~/.vim/swap/** in my vimrc, THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :)